# Bind dynamic array to column headers

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

How can I bind an array of changing data to the column headers?

I have seen that sample: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/302_custom_header

but its just displaying static data.

I need to bind the column headers to an array of date objects.

Answer (score 0):

The grid data can be configured to watch a scope variable. Here is an example where the data is loaded from a server call.

```
  angular.module('app', ['ngGrid'])
  .controller('GridCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    var grid = this;

    grid.exampleGrid = {
        enableCellSelection: false,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enableCellEdit: false,
        enableColumnResize: true,
        enableColumnReordering: true,
        data: 'gridData',
    };

    $http.get('/some/data/source').success(function(data){
      $scope.gridData = data
    });
  });
```

Server returning json

```
[
   {
         "Name": "Greg",
         "Date": 0
      },
   {
         "Name": "Marly",
         "Date": 7
      },
   {
         "Name": "Frank",
         "Date": 4
      }
]
```

With view

```
    <div ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller="GridCtrl as grid">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="grid.exampleGrid"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5RQgXLr5Mdf7GMw52nSN?p=preview)

**EDIT**

Updated my answer to reflect the clarification you made. 
ngGrid will automatically assign the json object keys to table headers if the json follows
the given structure.

updated the plunkr as well.

If you have no control over the structure of data coming from the server, you can modify
it to the structure.

Alternatively, the `grid.exampleGrid.columnDefs` can be set to watch a separate scope variable, which you can construct from the incoming data.

Comment: It seems you totally misunderstood me. Your sample does not reflect what I asked for. I want to bind the column headers to an array comming from example from the server. I do not want to setup the column names with hard coded values.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't exactly sure what you were asking for. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am still searching for the header code I would have expected:  $scope.gridHeaders ??? Where do you make use of this?

Comment: I will try this link this evening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405785/how-to-dynamically-configure-ng-grid and tell you whether it works!

Comment: Hadn't meant to leave that line in. I seem to be unsure what you're asking. What do you know about the data being received, and which parts are expected to change? I initially read "How can I bind an array of changing data to the column headers?" as an attempt to bind dynamic table data to a set of headers. If I'm understanding correctly now, you want dynamic headers. If that other example doesn't work for you I will make another attempt to provide the solution you're looking for.

Comment: ok thanks to my before link I can bind now my columndefs to my data coming from the service:  for(var i = 0; i <  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.length; i++){
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[i].field = datagridViewModel.columnsHeaderViewModel.columnHeaderDates[i];
    }